# bxSlider Custom pre next Button

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, bxslider

I want to use my own pre and next buttons and it is out of the slider div too. I am using BxSlider.
I will share my code a bit.
I will be glad if you can help this out.

This is the buttons and slides.

```
  <div class= "productsbuttons"><img id ="proprev" src="images/productleftarrow.png" /><img style="margin-left:10px;" id="pronext" src="images/productrightarrow.png" /> </div>
            </div>       
            <div class = "products">
              <ul class = "mainslider">
                <li><img class = "productslider" src="images/menu-image/img1.png" /> Lores ASda</li>
                <li><img class = "productslider" src="images/img1.png" /> ASDasdasd</li>
                <li><img class = "productslider" src="images/menu-image/img1.png" /> ASd</li>
                <li><img class = "productslider" src="images/img1.png" /> ASas</li>
              </ul>
```

This is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mySlider =   $('.mainslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#pronext',
  prevSelector: '#proprev',

  prevText: '',   
  nextText: '',
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideWidth: 360,
  slideMargin: 5,
  pager:false,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add your image `src` to `nextText` like this:

```
nextText: '<img src="images/next.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>',
prevText: '<img src="images/previous.jpg" height="25" width="25"/>'
```

Working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/1/) of an working example:

Comment: Doing this doesn't make any sense. Of course it will work, it's a simple solution but most of the time working on a slider with customized controls could require more styling and complex elements. Therefore I'd suggest making customized click event listeners and handle the controls yourself. This is way better imho and gives you more control on how it works and looks. Nevertheless, yes it will work but it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 16):

you can try this code below. This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var slider = $('.mainslider').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 2,
            slideWidth: 360,
            slideMargin: 5,
            pager:false,
    });

    $('#pronext').click(function(){
      slider.goToNextSlide();
      return false;
    });

    $('#proprev').click(function(){
      slider.goToPrevSlide();
      return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Having separated DOM elements requires writing style for them.